# ajax give me same data when call too frequently

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops, exit

I have a bar code gun, when i scan a bar code it will run the below function, but when I scan 5-6 bar code too fast it will give duplicate data

Also I need async to be true, or else it would be slow
Is there a way to do fix that so i don't have duplicate data?

```
function getUnReadBox() { 

$("#unReadBoxList").children().remove('li') ; 

$.ajax({ 
        dataType: "json",
        url: xxxx.php ,     
        success: saveUnRead , 
        error: function ( xhr , b , c ) { 
            $("#reportMsg").html ( "error" ) ;  },
        async: true }); 

}

function saveUnRead ( json ) { 

var i ; 
var new_item ; 
var msg ; 

for ( i in json ) { 
    new_item = '<li>' + json[i].PACKAGE_ID + "</li>" ; 
    $("#unReadBoxList").append ( new_item ) ; 
    scShipping.unReadBox ++ ; 

    $("#unReadBox").html ( msg ) ; 
}
$("#unReadBoxList").listview('refresh') ;
}
```

Edit

I added

```
$("#unReadBoxList").children().remove('li') ; 
 var d = new Date();
 var num = d.getTime();

var mySQL = scShipping.jsonUrl+'scTripUnRead.php?T='+scShipping.tripId+"&O="+scShipping.whichOp+"?date="+num ; 

$.ajax({ 
        dataType: "json",
        url: mySQL ,     
        success: saveUnRead , 
        error: function ( xhr , b , c ) { 
            $("#reportMsg").html ( "error" ) ;  },
        async: true }); 

}
```

but I still get duplicated data

Comment: Try appending `new Date().getTime()` to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue than you before. The solution that I got was passing in a numeric timestamp as a parameter when calling the php program, or passing in a date as parameter. Something like, for example:

xxxx.php?date=2014-03-28 20:54:52:03

It worked for me, I hope it works for you too...

Answer (score 0):

This happens may because the web browser cached the data you request,by avoiding this you can try these:

1. use `POST` instead of `GET` in your request. assign `POST` to `type` in the parameters of `$.ajax` method.
2. disable cache. assign `false` to `cache` in the parameters of `$.ajax` method.
3. append an additional parameter and value to the url,a random number or a timestamp,like this `xxxx.php?t=Math.random()` or `xxxx.php?t=new Date()`. these make sure your request urls are different, and the response data will not be cached.

Answer (score 0):

just like @user3311636 suggested, you can add an extra parameter on your Ajax calling code. So the server or your browser would not cache the response.

Try it like this (it is @user3311636 answer, i just include whole function for clarity purpose)

```
$.ajax({ 
    dataType: "json",
    url: "xxxx.php?date=2014-03-28 20:54:52:03" ,     
    success: saveUnRead , 
    error: function ( xhr , b , c ) { 
        $("#reportMsg").html ( "error" ) ;  },
    async: true });
```